# Javascript new effect on prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to bind a javascript object to an event listener and this is how I'm going about it:
(this is a simplified example, but it uses the pattern I'm interested in)

```
function foo(x){
    this.x = x;
}

foo.prototype = {
    'bar': function(){
       // do something with this.x
    },
    'events': function(){
        $(document).on('custom_event', function(event, x){
            var G = new foo(x);
            G.bar();
        });
    }
};

(function(){
    var G = new foo();
    G.events();
})();
```

So after the self-invoking anonymous function is run, every time `custom_event` is fired the bar method of my foo object will be called.

Questions:

When `new foo(x)` is called from within the event handler of my foo object, does it cause a duplication of the event listener?

It is my understanding that `prototype` methods belonging to an object are only created once and that calling `new foo()` only effects, in my case, `this.x`. If I am correct, I'm confused why it's necessary to use `new` from within the event listener in `foo`'s `events` method in order to use the prototype methods attached to `foo`.

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI: Probably just a copy & paste error, but your `events` is missing a `}`.

Comment: Your `custom_event` is only bound when `.events()` is called.  Since that event is bound to `document`, every time `.events()` is called *another* handler will be bound, yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "necessary to use new from within the event listener"?  You don't *need* to do `var G = new foo(x);`.  Depends on what you are trying to do.  You can't access `this` inside there, so you might want to do `var that = this; $(document).on('...', function(){ that.bar(); });`  This all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat - In `events` if I use `foo(x).bar()` instead of `new foo(x).bar()` I get `cannot read property 'bar' of undefined`.

Comment: Well, yeah.  `new foo(x)` *creates* a new `foo` object (thus inheriting the `prototype`).  `foo(x)` just calls the function, which for a constructor, won't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're mainly confused about the usage and effects of the `new` operator. I quote from [You Don't Know JS, this & object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2d043a5d3deabfc12ce2140728db3c6ae61b8234/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#new-binding):

> When a function is invoked with `new` in front of it, otherwise known as a constructor call, the following things are done automatically:
>
> 1. a brand new object is created (aka, constructed) out of thin air
> 2. *the newly constructed object is `[[Prototype]]`-linked*
> 3. the newly constructed object is set as the `this` binding for that function call
> 4. unless the function returns its own alternate **object**, the `new`-invoked function call will *automatically* return the newly constructed object.

Make sure you understand that well. On your questions:

> When `new foo(x)` is called from within the event handler of my foo object, does it cause a duplication of the event listener?

No. What you do with `new foo(x)` is use the `foo` function as a constructor, so you're only creating a new, prototypally linked, object (similar to `{}`) and then executing the code inside `foo`, with that new object as `this`. So that will result in an almost empty object, except for its property `x`. You're only setting up the event listener inside the `events` function!

> It is my understanding that `prototype` methods belonging to an object are only created once and that calling `new foo()` only effects, in my case, `this.x`. If I am correct, I'm confused why it's necessary to use `new` from within the event listener in `foo`'s `events` method in order to use the prototype methods attached to `foo`.

They are defined once, on the object you refer to as "the prototype" (which is really just the `prototype` property on the function `foo`), yes. And it's not necessary to use `new` here, all you're doing with that is creating a throwaway `foo` object inside a function of an already existing `foo` object.

What you'll likely want to do is not worry about setting `this.x` inside the constructor, but inside the event handler, before calling `bar()`:

```
something.on('custom_event', function(e, x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.bar();
});
```

The problem that you'll encounter here is that `this` in the context of the event handler will most likely be set/overridden by jQuery, and not point to the "`foo` object" you want to point to. To circumvent this problem, you need to either *lexically capture* the `this` at the moment of setting up the event handler (which is the `events` function):

```
events: function(){
    var self = this;
    $(document).on('custom_event', function(event, x){
        self.x = x;
        self.bar();
    });
}
```

or `bind` the `this` inside the callback handler to the "`foo` object" you want to reference:

```
events: function(){
    $(document).on('custom_event', (function(event, x){
        this.x = x;
        this.bar();
    }).bind(this));
}
```

See [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on MDN for some explanation of what this does.

---

Further note: I'm not sure what your custom event really is, but you're listening on the entire `$(document)` inside every single event handler. If you have DOM elements corresponding to each `foo` object, you should instead set these event handlers up on these specific DOM elements.